# Laravel 5.7 request validation doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel to submit a form. Here is my web.php routes :

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->prefix('account')->namespace('Account')->group(function () {
    Route::get('informations', 'AccountController@index')->name('account.informations');
    Route::post('informations', 'AccountController@update')->name('account.informations.post');
});
```

My Controller AccountController.php :

```
/**
 * @param UpdateMember $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function update(UpdateUser $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('account.informations');
}
```

And my UpdateUser.php :

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users|confirmed',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ];
}
```

My problem : when I use UserUpdate $request in my controller, I don't reach the function, the `dd($request->all())` is not shown.

But if I replace :

```
public function update(UpdateUser $request)
```

By

```
public function update(Request $request)
```

My controller is reached. What do I do wrong ?

Comment: That means there was a validation error, or authorization error. FormRequests are `validated` when they are resolved, which is before the method on your controller is called.

Comment: Validation errors are stored in the session so you will be able to see which part of the validation has failed

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to include the error view... I am so dumb. Thanks

Comment: Nothing dumb about that!

Comment: @VincentDecaux can you please explain a little how you solved? I am actually stuck.

Answer (score 0):

what about the unique field validation like email because your validation rules returns a error email already exists while updating a existing record. This can be solved as example below

```
    public function rules()
{
    $client = Client::find($this->client);
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'address' => 'required|string',
        'gender' => 'required|string',
        'dob' => 'required|string',
        'phone' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|unique:clients,email,' . $client->id,
        'password' => 'regex:/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/',
        'profile-photo' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
        'c_name' => 'nullable|regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/',
        'c_address' => 'nullable|regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/',
        'c_email' => 'nullable|email|unique:clients,company_email,'. $client->id,
        'c_contact' => 'nullable|regex:/^[0-9]*$/',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was that I forgt to add "Accept: application/json" in the request header. After adding that header everything worked fine